# Modify Taylor Digital Thermometer #3516 So that it Does Not Shutoff Automatically

Tags: automation

I want to mount a Taylor 3516 Digital Thermometer in a remote location that can still be seen. It is inconvenient to turn the temperature indicator back on after it has automatically shutoff. Can I modify the circuit to defeat the auto shutdown feature?

Comment: *Someone* probably can. Can you? We don't know.

Comment: Most likely the autoshutdown is a firmware feature. It is doubtful that it can be defeated with a simple circuit change. I think you would be better off getting a different product.

Comment: Not even a photo of the meter or link to the datasheet - never mind a schematic. -1.

Comment: If there is a button that only turns on, you could by figuring out the button wiring design something to periodically stimulate it.  But if it's the more common on/off toggle, you'd first have to figure out (via power consumption or LCD driver signals or similar) if it is already on.  Perhaps you should chose instead something *intended* for this application?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a circuit modification question. Please be aware that questions on the reverse engineering, modification and/or repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired, so that you can ask specific, focused questions that can be answered concisely. More information can be found [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2478/11683).

Answer (score 2):

Using external battery power and a 1 minute timer to pulse off the switch, the display can be kept On by restarting.

Or you can use a cheap analog solution.

[image]

Comment: And it is the same manufacturer which increases compatibility!